# Split an array into two. Predetermined sizes, might not always be equal

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I need to iterate over many files in a directory and split each file into two parts. I need to keep lines intact (I can't split on bite size). I also can't always assume that the file has an equal number of lines. I could use the "split" function, but am looking for a faster way of going through my files and to avoid the standard output names "xaa" and "xab" it generates.

The easiest would be to make two subsequent substrings of an array in the sizes specified ($number_of_group_one and $number_of_group_two). I can't find out how to do this. Instead I am trying to push the lines into different arrays- filling one up until a certain number of lines and then "spill over" into the other array until there are no more lines left to push. However, this approach yields two output arrays that both have exactly double the number of input lines. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($directory) = @ARGV;
my $dir = "$directory";
my @arrayoffiles = glob "$dir/*";
my @arrayoflines_one;
my @arrayoflines_two;
my $counter = 0;

foreach my $filename(@arrayoffiles){
    my @arrayoflines_one;
    my @arrayoflines_two;
    my @lines = read_lines($filename);
    my $NumberofLines = @lines;
    my $number_of_group_one = int($NumberofLines/2);
    my $number_of_group_two = ($NumberofLines - $number_of_group_one);
    foreach my $line (@lines){
            $counter++;
            push (@arrayoflines_one, $line, "\n");
            if ($counter == $number_of_group_one){
                    push (@arrayoflines_two, $line, "\n");
            }
    }
}

sub read_lines {
    my ($file) = @_;
    open my $in, '<', $file or die $!;
    local $/ = undef; #slurps the whole file in as one
    my $content = <$in>;
    return split /\s/, $content;
    close $in;
}
```

I hope this is clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you mean to say `$counter == $number_of_group_one`?

Comment: Yes! I will now update my post. That also changes the output. The first array is double the input, the second is empty (for most of my input files, not all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for `splice`:

```
 my @lines = read_lines($filename);
 my @lines1 = splice @lines, 0, @lines/2;
```

will put (about) half of your lines from `@lines` into `@lines1`, removing them (and leaving about half of the lines) from `@lines`.

Comment: I'd use `my @lines1 = splice @lines, @lines/2;`. Removing the second half is more straightfoward than removing from the first half.